# Rspec and observers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, observer-pattern

Currently writing some tests for my models. 
I have one model called Blog, when a user creates a blog an observer posts a message to the newsfeed of the user. 
One of my tests test that this is being done. This test, however, fails in the testing environment, doing the same thing within the console works flawlessly which leads me to believe that rspec is acting to fast and not waiting for the observer to finish doing its thing. Any way to get around this? Ive tried sleep but that doesnt seem to be working.

This is the general design.

Blog is created
Observer notices and creates a new Newsfeed and passes the new Blog object
Newsfeeds on create gets triggered and it gets the correct newsfeed message by calling a method on the Blog object. 
Newsfeed adds the blog to its newsfeed_items list and saves itself.

The spec fails because it doesnt wait for the observer to finish it task and calls its after method effectively deleting the object before the newsfeed object can get the message from it back.

Comment: ever figure this one out? I find that the observer hooks call once and then never again...

Answer (score 2):

Observers are not asynchronous (unless of course, you are queuing an asynchronous job in your observer callback).  The observed model itself is the sender of the callback methods.  It seems more likely that your observer is not observing in your tests.

Did you come across this thread?  Could it be of some use?
[How would you test observers with rSpec in a Ruby on Rails application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33048/how-would-you-test-observers-with-rspec-in-a-ruby-on-rails-application)

Comment: The observer is observer, some models work and some do not. Its all around very weird.